# Laravel whereRaw not returning anything

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have written my sqlquery in workbench first before actually moving it over to laravel code, and I can confirm this works.  Here is my sql query written in workbench

```
SET @info = 'hello';

SELECT device_type_id 
FROM arecibo.device_type_mappings
WHERE @info LIKE concat('%', name , '%') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I want to now convert this to code but am having troubles as it is not returning anything back.  I have googled around to see what I might be missing but to no avail I could not find anything.  Here is my attempted code:

```
$deviceTypeId = DB::table('device_type_mappings')
        ->select('device_type_id')
        ->whereRaw('? LIKE concat(\'%\', name , \'%\') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;', [$sysInfo])
        ->get();
```

if possible I would like to use the model, but it was complaining that there was no select method exposed.

I am using laravel 5.3

Comment: Check the laravel logs and the mysql logs. To be perfectly honest I don't see anything obviously wrong with your query. The ONLY thing that doesn't seem right is the `;` at the end of `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`, you don't need that.

Comment: Replace the `->get` with `->toSql()` dump this value and compare with what you expected and add it to this question if you need more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the semicolon from your 'where' statement, if this is being inserted into the query generated by Laravel then it may well not be able to run it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think think there is no problem to have it at your Model.

```
class Any extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'device_type_mappings';

    public static function getSomething()
    {
        $column = 'info';

        $a = self::whereRaw('? LIKE CONCAT(\'%\', name, \'%\') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci', [$column])->select('device_type_id');

        die($a->toSql());

        //OUTPUT: select `device_type_id` from `device_type_mappings` where ? LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
    }
}
```